# What could be the R code for Making an index?

Tags: r

Suppose we run a regression with dummy variables and we obtain results like

```
Yt=a+b1X1+b2X2+b3X3...+bnXn+C1Dum1+C2Dum2+C3Dum3+...+CnDumN
```

I want to create an index `I`, such that,

```
I=W1*Dum1+W2*Dum2+W3*Dum3+...+Wn*DumN
```

where Wi's are the weights as the regression coefficients of dummies.

Answer (score 0):

Supposed you have a data frame like this.

```
head(dat)
#      X1    X2     Y D1 D2 D3    W1    W2    W3
# 1  1.37 -0.31  0.21  0  1  0 -1.04  1.39 -0.03
# 2 -0.56 -1.78 -0.36  0  1  0 -0.09 -0.48  0.11
# 3  0.36 -0.17  0.76  0  1  0  0.62  0.65 -0.49
# 4  0.63  1.21 -0.73  0  1  0 -0.95  1.39 -0.50
# 5  0.40  1.90 -1.37  0  1  0 -0.54 -1.11 -1.66
# 6 -0.11 -0.43  0.43  0  1  0  0.58 -0.86 -0.38
```

You may use `which.max` to subset.

```
dat <- transform(dat, 
                 weight=apply(dat, 1, function(x) x[weights][which.max(x[dummies])]))
dat
#       X1    X2     Y D1 D2 D3    W1    W2    W3 weight
# 1   1.37 -0.31  0.21  0  1  0 -1.04  1.39 -0.03   1.39
# 2  -0.56 -1.78 -0.36  0  1  0 -0.09 -0.48  0.11  -0.48
# 3   0.36 -0.17  0.76  0  1  0  0.62  0.65 -0.49   0.65
# 4   0.63  1.21 -0.73  0  1  0 -0.95  1.39 -0.50   1.39
# 5   0.40  1.90 -1.37  0  1  0 -0.54 -1.11 -1.66  -1.11
# 6  -0.11 -0.43  0.43  0  1  0  0.58 -0.86 -0.38  -0.86
# 7   1.51 -0.26 -0.81  0  0  1  0.77 -1.13 -0.51  -0.51
# 8  -0.09 -1.76  1.44  0  0  1  0.46 -1.46  2.70   2.70
# 9   2.02  0.46 -0.43  1  0  0 -0.89  0.08 -1.36  -0.89
# 10 -0.06 -0.64  0.66  0  1  0 -1.10  0.65  0.14   0.65
# 11  1.30  0.46  0.32  0  0  1  1.51  1.20 -1.49  -1.49
# 12  2.29  0.70 -0.78  0  1  0  0.26  1.04 -1.47   1.04
# 13 -1.39  1.04  1.58  0  1  0  0.09 -1.00  0.12  -1.00
# 14 -0.28 -0.61  0.64  0  0  1 -0.12  1.85 -1.00  -1.00
# 15 -0.13  0.50  0.09  0  0  1 -1.19 -0.67  0.00   0.00
# 16  0.64 -1.72  0.28  0  1  0  0.61  0.11 -0.43   0.11
# 17 -0.28 -0.78  0.68  0  0  1 -0.22 -0.42 -0.61  -0.61
# 18 -2.66 -0.85  0.09  1  0  0 -0.18 -0.12 -2.02  -0.18
# 19 -2.44 -2.41 -2.99  0  0  1  0.93  0.19 -1.22  -1.22
# 20  1.32  0.04  0.28  0  1  0  0.82  0.12  0.18   0.12
```

---

*Data:*

I show here how I created the example data, which probably answers additional questions.

```
set.seed(42)
dat <- data.frame(matrix(round(rnorm(60), 2), 20, 3))
dat$X4 <- rbinom(20, 2, .5)
names(dat)[3] <- "Y"
dat <- cbind(dat[-4], setNames(data.frame(model.matrix(X1 ~ 0 + factor(X4), dat)),
                               paste0("D", 1:3)))
dat <- cbind(dat, setNames(data.frame(matrix(round(rnorm(60), 2), 20, 3)),
                           paste0("W", 1:3)))
```